# Firebase A/B Test with Remote Config doesn't work with specific version on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I created A/B Test with Remote Config 2 days ago and add specific version with Regular expression `1\.4\.1[3-9]`. But firebase dashboards shows that 0 users.

Remote Config & Remote Config Key, Regular Expression works perfectly

I'm using

**Fireabse 4.5.0**

**FirebaseRemoteConfig (2.1.0)**

The problem is that, after two days, the Firebase Console keeps saying that 0 users have

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you manage to solve yours?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a bug with remote config. It uses build version of your application instead of app version